# Is there a word for a bright spot in the shadow of a lens or lens-like object?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Or for example on the bottom of a pool as light is focused by waves on the surface of the water. It seems awkward to just call it a shadow since it implies being darker than the surroundings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are called ***caustics***, the randomly fluctuating patterns of bright lines at the bottom of the pool. They are caused by reflection and refraction of sunlight at the perturbed pool surface illuminated by the sun.

The *rippling caustics* seen below are so called because they are caused by concentration of sunlight (with the resultant potential of causing a burn).

More details on this phenomenon can be found [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch02.html).

[image]
<sub>(source: [toronto.edu](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/%7Estam/INRIA/Images/caustic_depth_02.gif))</sub>

Comment: Can you mention some references?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not subscribe to physics journals and would not be able to point you to any authoritative source. Hope this link helps - http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch02.html

Comment: If you think it helps, you should include it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you describe, the opposite of a shadow is a *focus*, plural (usually) *foci*:

> 1. a.  A point at which rays of light or other radiation converge or from which they appear to diverge, as after refraction or reflection in an optical system: the focus of a lens. Also called  focal point.
>      [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/focus)

Comment: I don't think this definition applies for cases where it is an only slightly brighter spot on a shadow cast onto an object that is not actually in the focal plane.